# SQL : How to create one table with use pivot or case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

| ID | condition | start time | end time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | baseline | 15/06/2018 | 16/04/2015 |
| M01 | tactical | 03/04/2001 | 06/12/2017 |
| M02 | tactical | 30/06/2007 | 18/08/2002 |
| M02 | baseline | 19/07/2001 | 06/09/2007 |
| M03 | baseline | 09/12/2015 | 30/07/2014 |
| M03 | tactical | 17/07/2002 | 09/05/2009 |

I will obtain this table witch condition on "baseline" or "tactical" :

| ID | baseline start time | baseline end time | tactical start time | tactical end time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | 15/06/2018 | 16/04/2015 | 03/04/2001 | 06/12/2017 |
| M02 | ------ | -------- | ------- | ------- |
| M03 | ------ | -------- | ------- | ------- |

I would like to use pivot or case in SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this and probably the old case when is the easiest to do:

```
SELECT id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN condition = 'baseline' THEN [start time] END) [baseline start time],
    MAX(CASE WHEN condition = 'baseline' THEN [end time] END) [baseline end time],
    MAX(CASE WHEN condition = 'tactical' THEN [start time] END) [tactical start time],
    MAX(CASE WHEN condition = 'tactical' THEN [end time] END) [tactical end time]
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY id;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c7cbaa3457e8ee64977ddacf016c714)

Yet another way:

```
WITH ids AS (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM myTable)
SELECT *
FROM ids i
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT [start time], [end time]
                 FROM myTable t
                 WHERE i.ID=t.ID AND t.condition='baseline') bl([baseline start time], [baseline end time])
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT [start time], [end time]
                 FROM myTable t
                 WHERE i.ID=t.ID AND t.condition='tactical') tc([tactical start time], [tactical end time]);
```